# How can I use sum function in R?

Tags: r, statistics, probability

This is my first post here and I couldn't find the answer I was looking for.
I'm currently taking edX course on Probability in Data Science, but I got stuck on section 1.
The task asks you to simulate a series of 6 games with random, independent outcomes of either a loss (0) or win(1), and then use the sum function to determine whether a simulated series contained at least 4 wins.
Here's what I did:

```
l <- list(0:1)

n <- 6

games <- expand.grid(rep(l, n))

games <- paste (games$Var1, games$Var2, games$Var3, games$Var4, games$Var5, games$Var6)
sample (game, 1, replace = TRUE)
```

but I can't seem to use the sum function to sum the result of '''sample''' and check if there's a series of at least 4 games. I've been trying to use
`sum(sample (game, 1, replace = TRUE))`
but can't seem to get anywhere with it.

Any light would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what one simulated series look like

```
sample(c(0, 1), 6, replace = TRUE)
```

To count number of wins (i.e 1) you could use `sum` like

```
sum(sample(c(0, 1), 6, replace = TRUE)) >= 4
```

Now you could generate such series `n` times with `replicate`.

```
n <- 1000
replicate(n, sum(sample(c(0, 1), 6, replace = TRUE)) >= 4)
```

---

If you have to use `games` to calculate you can use `rowSums` to count number of 1's

```
sum(rowSums(games) >= 4)
#[1] 22
```

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was looking for. I guess I need to familiriaze myself with the syntax.